# Question about 男女比 order

Tags: translation, words

How is 男女比 used in this example? Just like anything else in japanese context matters and in this case the male/famale ratio is 6 male and 4 female, because the text is talking about females are *coming back little by little* in some context.

> 少しずつ女性が盛り返してきていますが、いま男女比はだいたい６：４くらいです。

Am I mising anything? Is this complete bs?

Comment: hello from 2016! https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/31087/the-order-after-%e7%94%b7%e5%a5%b3%e6%af%94

Comment: So in this case it would be correct to understand this as 6:4 male female?

Comment: @oozeman Yes, 60% is male, 40% is female, unless the context clearly indicates the opposite.